# .htaccess rewrite not working (with js and css version)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to create a `.htaccess` rewrite. All requests need to redirect to `/public/index.php`. except for assets. (`public/images/, public/css/ etc...`). My css and js files have version (`style.20180523.css`). So the numbers need to get remove from the file name.

Example link:

```
domain.com/users/123 -> to index.php
```

`domain.com/public/images/logo.png` -> All requests which start with public, will remain unchanged If css or js remove a number

Here is my htaccess:

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        RewriteRule ^(?!\/public) public/index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a rewrite condition like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/(css|js)/
```

before your RewriteRule.

This will rewrite everything that is not starting with /public/css or /public/js

Comment: Thank you for your help!